# Android - Is it Possible to rotate ViewPager like ViewFlipper

Tags: android

I have a ViewPager contain PageA, PageB, PageC

I want my ViewPager to show PageC when swipe left in PageA.

For example,

When the current page is PageA, by swiping right-to-left can i get PageC

Similarly When in PageC, by swiping left-to-right can i get PageA.

i.e I want my ViewPager to rotate.

Comment: refer this post if u want to simply move your pages from left to right and reverse http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9276234/androidsynchronization-of-images-on-fling-and-onclick-also-to-show-previous-and/9279029#9279029

Comment: @VivekKhandelwal did you got the solution ? can you please post it ?